# How to stop all validations after the first failure in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

There is a function called [`bail`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) in Laravel that stops the validation upon failure. What if I want to stop ALL validations upon first failure?

For example:

```
$request->validate([
    'antibotprotection' => 'bail|required|exists:protectioncodes,protection_code|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
]);
```

This code will stop validation  of the `antibotprotection` but then it will continue to validate the email and pass errors to view about the email as well, which defeats the whole purpose. How would I stop this whole `validate` function upon the first failure?

Comment: I don't think Laravel had this feature. Why you need to stop the validation after first error? Isn't it better to show the user all their mistake is previous attempt?

Comment: @Zendy not always. A malicious bot could extract a list of emails that are registered within the system by attempting to register emails and see which return "email already registered" error.

Comment: create new class custom validation rule. then just throw exception instead of return the error message.

Comment: You could call `$request->validate()` twice, the first time only with the antibot rule, and a second time with your remaining rules. If the first one fails, a ValidationException is thrown and the second doesn't run.

Comment: You can check `antibotprotection` manually without using Laravel built-in validation or as@TobiasK said, you can use 2 validator to achieve what you want

Comment: @ArthurTarasov aren't captchas solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: @ArthurTarasov below is an answer that should do what you need, let me know if you have further questions about it 

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I need a single version to work in all countries (including China) and not rely on a language so I'm stuck inventing my own

Comment: @ArthurTarasov IMHO, [Google's reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language) is a quite nice soluion.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I gave it a lot of thought. Google captcha is blocked in China. But it's not really why I don't like it. It is tailored for websites with advertisements. Mine is a paid service so I don't care if a bot is logging in if it paid the money. Then it is a good bot, welcome :) Google's blanked bot ban seems like an excessive force with unwanted casualties. Also google tracking visitors' IPs is a big deal. A shiny sales pitch of this system is that user's private info will never be shared with any 3rd party. Finally, those modern captchas are not easy to solve for some users.

Answer (score 1):

`./app/Validation/BailingValidator.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class BailingValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * Determine if the data passes the validation rules.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes()
    {
        $this->messages = new MessageBag;

        // We'll spin through each rule, validating the attributes attached to that
        // rule. Any error messages will be added to the containers with each of
        // the other error messages, returning true if we don't have messages.
        foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules) {
            $attribute = str_replace('\.', '->', $attribute);

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $this->validateAttribute($attribute, $rule);

                if ($this->shouldStopValidating($attribute)) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        // Here we will spin through all of the "after" hooks on this validator and
        // fire them off. This gives the callbacks a chance to perform all kinds
        // of other validation that needs to get wrapped up in this operation.
        foreach ($this->after as $after) {
            call_user_func($after);
        }

        return $this->messages->isEmpty();
    }
}
```

`./app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
...
use App\Validation\BailingValidator;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
...
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * @var \Illuminate\Validation\Factory $factory
         */
        $factory = resolve(Factory::class);

        $factory->resolver(function (Translator $translator, array $data, array $rules, array $messages, array $customAttributes) {
            return new BailingValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
        });
    }
...
```

`./app/Http/Controller/SomeController.php`

```
...
        $this->validate($request, [
            'foo' => ['bail', 'required'],
            'bar' => ['bail', 'required'],
        ]);
...
```

`{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"foo":["The foo field is required."]}}`

Comment: basically all this does is that it adds a `2` after the break code where laravel detects a `bail` rule is used, note that the `bail` rule for `bar` is not strictly necicairy in this example, since if `foo` bailed it won't even look at the `bail` rule of bar*

Comment: Thank you that's very interesting! I upvoted your answer, but I think I'll leave this question without accepted answer for a bit maybe someone has a bit lighter solution or maybe it will inspire another validation rule in Laravel 6 or something

Comment: Agreed, its not the perfect answer, but it will do for your specific use case 

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. @ArthurTarasov did you find an easy way in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem i used `array_unique` to remove repetitive error code from the `$errors` array, i know it only solve the display part, but still to me that's all i care about. Here's an example:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach (array_unique($errors->all()) as $error)
            <div>{!! ucfirst($error) !!}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```